# Fetching weather data from API

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, programming-challenge, functional-programming

I was experimenting with some code to fetch the `current` weather data as well as getting the `hourly` forecast. I could have done written some functions to get the thing done but I want to learn object composition to learn more about it. Below is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const weatherService = {
  fetch: async endpoint => await axios.get(endpoint)
}

const weatherApi = {
  currentWeather: async city => {
    try {
      const { data: { data } } = await this.service.fetch(this.config.endpoints.curr + city)
      return this.handleCurrentData(data)
    } catch(e) {
      this.handleError(e)
    }
  },
  hourlyForecast: async city => {
    try {
      const { data: { data } } = await this.service.fetch(this.config.endpoints.hour + city)
      return this.handleHourlyData(data)
    } catch(e) {
      this.handleError(e)
    }
  }
};

const defaultConfig = {
  endpoints: {
    curr: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=`,
    hour: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=`
  }
};

const api = (api, config, service) => {
  return {
    Object.create(weatherApi),
    Object.create(service),
    Object.create(config),
    ...obj
  }
};

// dependency injection for testing
module.exports = (obj, config=defaultConfig, service=weatherService) => {
  return api(obj, config, service)
};


// Usage
const weatherAPI = require('api')({
  handleCurrentData: (data) => console.log(data),
  handleHourlyData: (data) => console.log(data)
});

weatherAPI.currentWeather('London');
weatherAPI.hourlyWeather('London');
```

I would like to know if my approach is correct? also, what can I do to improve the readability, flexibility of the code?

Comment: You're using ES6 arrow functions, so why not use ES6 classes?

Comment: Does this code even work? I spot a few things that indicate it doesn't.

Comment: Has this code changed since last July? If so, are you able to update it? Like Joesph commented: it appears not to work..